# Compose Redux with HOC in export component in React

Tags: reactjs

I don't know how to compose Redux with onClickOutside HOC in my component export...
I tried sth like this but didn't work

```
export default compose(
        connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),
        onClickOutside)
        (DropMenu, clickOutsideConfig);
```

Error I got :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReactComponent' of undefined
```

Comment: what react version do you user? @poldeeek

Comment: try read [this](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside/issues/327#issue-480239163) issue ma bro

Comment: From package.js -> "react": "^16.13.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without using the redux `compose` method. Try something like the following:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(onClickOutside(DropMenu))
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with the `clickOutsideConfig`, but you can always pass it in as props to `DropMenu`.